# Free console TCP tunneling app or proxifier

Tags: windows, gratis, networking, portable

I need an application that will make certain applications that have no proxy support by itself (browser, for example) to go through my SOCKS proxy server.

Requirements:

- No GUI-actions needed (CLI only or simply hiding the GUI)
- Portable, configuration file is stored in the same directory
- Works on Windows 7/8
- Free to distribute and use

We have [ProxyChains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) on Linux, but I can't find any suitable app for Windows.
[Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) works as expected, but it's not free.

Comment: I use PuTTY; I can't do a full write up now but I can in the morning

Comment: @Luke, I would appreciate it. I've seen it but didn't realize would it help me or not. I'm not yet familiar with SSH tunneling.

Comment: If you need a proxy application for a program that doesn't give proxy configuration, then PuTTY won't work (good thing too, since someone beat me to the write up)

Comment: Proxifier is great but [not flawless](http://superuser.com/q/752008/116475) :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (free).

1. Uncheck "Don't start a shell or command at all" in PuTTY, tab Connection->SSH.
2. Create a `.bat` containing `putty -N -D 9990 -P 22 your_server_IP` and run it (and don't close the window)

Configure your browser to use the tunnel, e.g. for Firefox:

[image]

Comment: No. I need to proxify an application that has no proxy support. There is no such option as "proxy configuration" at all. If there was, then there were no need in any proxifier. Edited question, sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: @Agath oh OK, then yeah I use proxifier as you mention in your question :) I'll leave my answer for other readers (like myself in the future) in case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FreeCap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng)

- Free to distribute and use
- Works on Windows
- Not portable but the configuration can be exported
- GUI can be hidden
- reroute connections from programs through the SOCKS server (v4 and v5 supported)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

FYI: [Comparison of proxifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers) (my favorite is Proxifier)

Comment: Sadly, but FreeCap is outdated. I've tested it before asking the question. It works with old applications, but it doesn't work with applications that use new versions of winsock/wininet libraries, because it's based on injection.

Comment: Thanks good to know, yes I hadn't used it extensively before switching to proxifier.