# Free ProxyCap-like proxifier for Windows with support for HTTP proxy

Tags: windows, gratis, proxy

I am looking for a program that lets me add proxy support for all my applications without having to configure every single one (particularly because some applications I use don't have proxy support). I am working in a company which uses a corporate proxy and having to set up proxy for all the applications is a pain (double pain since I have to disable the proxy when I'm home).

I need a program that has support for HTTP proxies.

I have tried Freecap (not working with new applications, as said in this question [Free console TCP tunneling app or proxifier](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/free-console-tcp-tunneling-app-or-proxifier)) and WideCap (supports only https connections, not plain http).

I couldn't find any other good application from this list on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers

I have used ProxyCap for the evaluation month and it did exactly what I needed, now I can't find an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues, depending on the windows version.  From Windows 8, with the introduction of the "Modern" UI applications (previously called "Metro" apps), new Windows APIs were introduced for these apps to connect which didn't go through the same pathway, and the upshot of this is that the LSP (Layered Service Provider) of Windows Sockets no longer worked. so socksifiers based solely around LSP technology wouldn't work for those apps (only for Desktop/traditional/legacy apps).

To work with metro apps on Windows 8 and later, the socksifier needs to use the Windows Filtering Platform (WFP).

There are several paid products we have used to successfully test with our SOCKS server ([WinGate](http://www.wingate.com)).  I can recommend Proxifier, and also the OpenText client.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com).

Answer (score 0):

There exists [KKcap](https://www.kkcap.net), which worked for me. You will need to add there Proxy, then select AppNames, and activate the rules.

Comment: how do you add an http proxy?